# Good Java community and resource

Tags: java, resources

I've just started learning Java as part of my uni course, and am so far really liking it. I did a quick search to try and find a Java Community online, but haven't really had any luck. I was looking for something along the lines of gotoandlearn.com and www.kirupa.com like the flash communities have.

Can anyone recommend a good starting point and friendly place for a java n00b?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You can try javaranch.com. It is one of most active Java community on Internet.

Comment: Righly said. Got 4 second late. :) +1

Comment: Ha ha .. Gotta move your fingers more faster on keyboard ;-) ... Jst Kidding.

Comment: Haha.... it was because the idea of linking the resources. Bad idea. :)

Answer (score 10):

- [Javaranch.com](http://www.javaranch.com/)
- [CodeRanch Forums](http://www.coderanch.com/forums)

Comment: +1 for links, even if you were slightly later than shuby.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Java Blackbelt](http://www.javablackbelt.com) which provides quizzes and tests that may help you learn.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to see http://www.theserverside.com/ plus others recommended by other people here. But if you are a noob [thinking in Java by Bruce Ecke](http://www.mindview.net/Books/TIJ4)l is a good starting point IMO. Cant always trust things you find in blogs etc IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Sun has a [Java forum](http://forums.sun.com/index.jspa).   Sign up for an ID and browse away.  It can be a rough place for new people, unlike Java Ranch.  I think it's improved since they added moderators.  But it's 100% Java, all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [comp.lang.java.programmer newsgroup](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.programmer/topics)? (There's also [comp.lang.java.help](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.help/topics), which is more "newbie-oriented", but has less traffic.)