# Is there something like dotnetkicks.com for Java

Tags: java

I'm totally a newbie-programmer and I've just joined to Java World, so I need a place to hear pros talking about it.

With .NET, I have the dotnetkicks.com, dotnetshoutout.com, etc.

So, anyone know something like that for Java?

Comment: There's this cool site called stackoverflow.com, I can only recommend it! ;-)

Comment: Just for clarification: what **exactly** are you looking for? Coding help? News? Chit-chat? Programming Tips from Pros?

Comment: Thanks everybody to take interest with my question, the links you gave me help me a lot but none of them satisfy me. 
@ Joachim Sauer (and all): As you know, daily, thousands articles about java are being written and posted somewhere on the net and a link-share-site like dotnetkicks.com helps us to focus (and dont miss) high quality ones.

Answer (score 13):

Try http://www.javaranch.com. It is aimed at helping people learn Java and earning certifications.

Answer (score 4):

Also consider http://TheServerSide.com and http://java.dzone.com/ .

Answer (score 2):

Yes you have its [Stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) Where you are currently asking this question.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer, you're the first to comment! Didn't you suggest the same thing? :-)

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: when I posted my (now deleted) comment the answer contained different links (or I misread or halucinated).

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman, @Joachim: First I misunderstood question and posted java orcale's link but when I looked what the links are posted by OP I updated my answer. As I only know SO for Q&A I posted link to SO.

Answer (score 1):

There **was** `forums.java.sun.com` which was a pretty vibrant forum (not really news, but mostly help). It was integrated into the [Oracle Forums](http://forums.oracle.com/) which reduced its activity quite a lot ('though many former Java forum members are around here).

For news-ish stuff about (server-side) Java [The Server Side](http://www.theserverside.com/) isn't too bad.

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for something like http://www.java-forums.org/ or http://javaprogrammingforums.com/ . Google for java forum to find similar sites.

Answer (score 0):

[Good Java community and resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736940/good-java-community-and-resource)